# Concatenate String to send multiple images to server android

Tags: android, base64, stringbuilder

I need to send multiple images from android device to php server. so encoded the images to base64 and then to string format but now i need to concatenate all the image's base64 with comma as seperator and send in `List<NameValuePair>` with single key/name. I have tried to use append() with StringBuilder but coud not get appended list with comma.

**Here's my code:**

```
if (ar2.size() != 0) {
    for(int i=1;i<ar2.size();i++){
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ar2.get(i));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(b, 0);
        encodedString = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(encodedString)).append(",").toString();
    }//end of for
    Log.e("Multiple Images with comma seperated :", encodedString);
}
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newsImages", encodedString));
```

**My question**: Is it possible to send multiple images encoded base64 as single string with comma seperator to server?

I'm Stuck in appending line:

```
encodedString = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(encodedString)).append(",").toString();
```

Comment: What you get in server side? Does it add new lines instead?

Comment: actually when i viewed logcat i get only one string without comma

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

instead of

```
encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(b, 0);
```

Something like:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
stringBuilder.append(encodedString);
stringBuilder.append(",");
```

Comment: Still the same just line seperator is removed

Comment: still same... comme is not appended to the string

Comment: Thanks. I was using Base64.DEFAULT and, after I changed to Base64.NO_WRAP, I got the result that I wanted.